# Is it possible to use different tokens in metatag based on content type

Tags: 7, tokens, meta-tags

Lets say I have the summary field enabled on article type but not on page type and then I setup meta tag descriptions to use the token [node:summary] would is be possible to do something like if [node:summary] doesn't exist or is empty than use [node:body] ?

Otherwise i was would most likely need to add the summary field to page types and fill the summary field for all the pages that didnt have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Drupal 7**

When you configure Metatag, you can click on `+ Add default meta tags` and this will allow you to **set them up by Content Type**.

[image]

[image]

You will see this gets added to the config tree. Simply now edit the content type you just added.

## Bonus/Extra Info

If you need to alter **only specific nodes**, edit your node and scroll down to the end and select the Meta tags tab.

[image]